# getting NULL in @RequestPayload

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I am using Spring WS and I have one WSDL,that was already generated.

My WSDL:
....

```
<xs:complexType name="invokeBoarding_Opera">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BoardingRequest" type="tns:BoardingRequest"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BoardingRequest">
<xs:sequence>
....
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

....

InvokelBoarding_Opera.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "invokelBoarding_Opera",namespace="http://boardingImpl.webservices.com/")
public class InvokeBoarding_Opera {
    private BoardingRequest BoardingRequest;
```

I was tried to from SOAP UI, but i am getting NULL values

Comment: And where is your Spring-WS method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed spring ws to apache cxf. Now its working fine